# Mail headers missing via SMTP in office365

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Here is peculiar case only found on `office365` and not on `outlook.com`.

When I send email with a custom header set (`X-ArchiveNum`) via O365 SMTP. I am able to send email. But the receiver does not receive the headers when fetched via IMAP. This issue exists only with office365.

```
Transport transport = getTransport();
MimeMessage forward = new MimeMessage(getSession());
forward.addHeader("X-ArchiveNum", num);
forward.setSubject(sMessage.getSubject());
forward.setFrom(InternetAddress.parse(from)[0]);
forward.setText(body);
forward.saveChanges();
transport.sendMessage(forward, InternetAddress.parse(to));
```

I see the header being set, when I goto `Sent Items` folder in my `outlook.office365.com` account:
[image]

I also see the header on the browser when viewed from recipient account. But when I fetch the email via IMAP, I do not see it. *I can see the other O365 related headers*, but not mine.

Things work as expected from `outlook.com` (not O365)

Comment: Sounds like a bug that you need to report to Microsoft.